# Magento 2 php bin/magento could not open file

Tags: magento2

I've got a big problem. I need to `reindex` most of my index in Magento but when I try with `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` I've the following problem.

> Could not open input file: bin/magento

**Magento backoffice**

[image]

**the terminal command lines**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please take a minute to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [Writing the perfect question.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and try writing a better question, good luck!

Comment: Try expanding on this error message you are getting and provide the code that fails, showing us what you have tried already.

Comment: thanks I add screenshots to the question hope somebody can help me

Comment: First, double check the file exists from where you are calling it - does this `bin/magneto` file have an absolute path? try calling it from the root (`/`) directory to make sure you are calling the right one, secondly [check you have the correct permissions](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/checking-linux-file-permissions-with-ls/)

Comment: windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem again, the writing rights on the directory were alright, the bin directory was still empty after a composer install.

This time it was solved by doing:

`rm -rf vendor` and `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bin/magento file doesn't have the right permissions.

Try to add execute perm and check the user owner.

```
chmod u+x bin/magento
```